# PL/SQL Update with cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I anonymous block which should remove everything before @ in email column.

```
DECLARE
   v_id NUMBER(10);
   v_email VARCHAR2(30);
   i NUMBER(1) := 0;
   CURSOR cursor_name IS 
      SELECT Id, (substr (email, instr (email,'@',1) + 1 )) AS Domain
      FROM invoices
      WHERE id=31232681;
BEGIN
   OPEN cursor_name;
   LOOP
      v_email := '@' || v_email;
      FETCH cursor_name INTO v_id, v_email;
         UPDATE invoices
         SET email = v_email
         WHERE Id =  v_id;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cursor_name;
END;
```

But getting PLS-00103 error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
     := . ) , @ % default character 
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue
```

Can help me to know what is the problem?

**Solution**
Semi colon was missing at:

> EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;

Comment: You don't need a cursor or PL/SQL for this. Why don't you simply use `update invoices set email = substr(....) where id = 31232681;`

Comment: Currently posted code lacks in semi-colon at the end of the `EXIT WHEN ...` line. But yes, as @a_horse said - what's the purpose of PL/SQL, when `update` does that itself?

Comment: He is concatenating the values, he maybe have multiple rows for the same Id, and want to concatenate the email

Answer (score 0):

Could you try that?

```
DECLARE    
 v_id NUMBER(10);
 v_email VARCHAR2(30);
 i NUMBER(1) := 0;

 CURSOR cursor_name IS 
  SELECT Id, (substr (email, instr (email,'@',1) + 1 )) AS Domain
  FROM invoices
  WHERE id=31232681;

BEGIN
 OPEN cursor_name;
 LOOP
  v_email := '@' || v_email;
  FETCH cursor_name INTO v_id, v_email;
   UPDATE invoices
   SET email = v_email
   WHERE Id =  v_id;
   EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE cursor_name;
END;
```

I've seen your solution now, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your answer will be more helpful to others (and more likely to get upvotes), however, if you explain what you're doing and why it will solve the user's problem